# Appending data to JSON response depending on status code of JSON response

Tags: python, json

I have been using the following to append information to a JSON response.

```
for result in results:
    if result["status"] == "OK":
        for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
            route['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
```

Where origincoords is a list of coordinates. The number of origincoords is equal to the number of JSON dictionaries I have.

This works fine assuming the JSON response returned is valid (i.e. "Status": 'OK').

However, if for whatever reason it is not (for example, Unknown_Error, Not_Found etc) the above will fail as the relevant origincoords cannot be paired with their relevant JSON response. 1. the integrity of the data is lost and 2. there isnt an equal amount of JSON dictionaries to origincoords thus an index error is raised and 3.the location to insert the data is not possible with the path given ['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] as it wont exist when a status != "OK" is returned.

I have tried the following to overcome this -

```
for result in results:
    for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
        if result["status"] == "OK":
            route['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
        if result["status"] != "OK":
            route[u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
```

However this also returns an IndexError

```
    route['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I maintain the integrity of the appended information to their JSON responses in the scenario of a JSON response with an error?

EDIT. My desired outcome.

In this example, the first result has an unknown error, the second is OK and the third has an unknown error.

```
origincoords = ['51.51964085,-0.092434321',
 '51.51963442,-0.092433965',
 '51.52208762,-0.095990014']

results = [{u'routes': [], u'status': u'UNKNOWN_ERROR'},
{u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                               u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value}},
                   u'copyrights': u'value',
                   u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                   u'summary': u’value’,
                   u'warnings': [],
                   u'waypoint_order': []}],
      u'status': u'OK'},
    {u'routes': [], u'status': u'UNKNOWN_ERROR'}]
```

I would like to pair the first set of origincoords to the first JSON response, the second to the second JSON etc.

Thus

```
 results = [{u'routes': [], u'status': u'UNKNOWN_ERROR', u'_sent_origin': '51.51964085,-0.092434321'},
    {u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                                  u'lng': value},
                                   u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                                  u'lng': value}},
                       u'copyrights': u'value',
                       u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                       u'summary': u’value’,
                       u'warnings': [],
                       u'waypoint_order': []}],
          u'status': u'OK',
          u'_sent_origin': '51.51963442,-0.092433965'}],
        {u'routes': [], u'status': u'UNKNOWN_ERROR', u'_sent_origin': '51.52208762,-0.095990014'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing two loops instead of one!

Solution -

```
for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
    if route["status"] == "OK":
        route['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
    else:
        route[u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
```

I didn't need to do two loops. I was doing 'for result in results' and 'for route, origincoord in izip(results, originscoords):'

Answer (score 1):

Your complete set-up is not clear to me from the snippet you posted, but it seems you need to check the status before iterating over the `izip`.

```
for result in results:
        if result["status"] == "OK":
            for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
                route['routes'][0]['legs'][0][u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
        else
            for route, origincoord in izip(results, origincoords):
                route[u'_sent_origin'] = origincoord
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaz. This still results in an IndexError. I've added further details to my question in the hope of making it clearer